# MapReduce: Reduce function is writing strange values that are not expected

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

My reduce function in Java is writing on the output file values that are not expected. I inspect my code with breakpoints and I saw that, for each `context.write` call that I made, the key and the value that I'm writing are correct. Where am I making mistakes?

What I'm trying to do is taking in input row of type date, customer, vendor, amount that represent transactions and generate a dataset with row like date, user, balance where the balance is the sum of all transactions in which user was both customer or vendor.

Here is my code:

```
public class Transactions {
 
    public static class TokenizerMapper
            extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{
 
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            var splittedValues = value.toString().split(",");
            var date = splittedValues[0];
            var customer = splittedValues[1];
            var vendor = splittedValues[2];
            var amount = splittedValues[3];
            var reduceValue = new Text(customer + "," + vendor + "," + amount);
            context.write(new Text(date), reduceValue);
        }
    }
 
    public static class IntSumReducer
            extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
 
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                           Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Map<String, Integer> balanceByUserId = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            values.forEach(transaction -> {
                var splittedTransaction = transaction.toString().split(",");
                var customer = splittedTransaction[0];
                var vendor = splittedTransaction[1];
                var amount = 0;
                if (splittedTransaction.length > 2) {
                    amount = Integer.parseInt(splittedTransaction[2]);
                }
                if (!balanceByUserId.containsKey(customer)) {
                    balanceByUserId.put(customer, 0);
                }
                if (!balanceByUserId.containsKey(vendor)) {
                    balanceByUserId.put(vendor, 0);
                }
                balanceByUserId.put(customer, balanceByUserId.get(customer) - amount);
                balanceByUserId.put(vendor, balanceByUserId.get(vendor) + amount);
            });
 
            balanceByUserId.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
                var reducerValue = new Text(entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue().toString());
                try {
                    context.write(key, reducerValue);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "transactions");
        job.setJarByClass(Transactions.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> where the balance is the sum of all transactions in which user was both customer or vendor

`balanceByUserId` exists only for each **unique date** since your map key is the date.

If you want to aggregate **by customer info** (name / ID?), then **`customer`** should be the key of the mapper output.

Once all data from each customer is grouped by the reducer, you can then sort by date, if needed, but aggregate by other details.

---

Also worth pointing out that this would be easier in Hive or SparkSQL rather than Mapreduce.